# foreach delay fadein jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to delay my css fade in for each div using jquery. I need the elements to fade in one after the other. At the moment they are simply fading in at the same time.

Here is my jquery:

```
$(".service").each(function(i, el) {
    var el = $(el);
    if (el.visible(true)) {  
        $(this).delay(800*i, function(){
            el.addClass("animated fadeInDown"); 
        });
    } 
  });
```

Please help.

Comment: I don't think jQuery takes a function as 2nd argument in delay. The docs say `string`... http://api.jquery.com/delay/ - so go for the `setTimeout` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use setTimeout:

```
$(".service").each(function (i, el) {
    var el = $(el);
    if (el.visible(true)) {
        setTimeout(function () {
           el.addClass("animated fadeInDown");
        }, 800 * i);
    }
});
```